# Enable multiplayer capabilities in iOS game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-center

Im a bit new to iOS game development and I was wanting to create a game that allows two people to battle head to head to complete for a score or prize. I have been searching for hours on how to do this but have not been able to find anything. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's Apple's documentation on Real Time Matchmaking, which is what you need to do real time online multiplayer.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH9-SW1

Here's a tutorial on creating a simple multiplayer game with Sprite Kit and Real Time Matchmaking
https://www.raywenderlich.com/60980/game-center-tutorial-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-sprite-kit-part-1

https://www.raywenderlich.com/60998/game-center-tutorial-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-sprite-kit-part-2

Just use this knowledge and apply it to what you're making.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without game center?